# MVC 5, angularJs, Actionmethod does not redirect to the view

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC5 + angularJS project.
I have an angularjs code that hits  MVC controller. And I expect the view to show. But The view does not come up. the screen remains the same.

My MVC method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult InitiatePayment()
    {

        string strForm="";

        return View(model: strForm);


    }
```

When I access the controller from URL the view comes up.

But when I access the method from angularJs method, the view does not come up. The old screen remains as it is. There are no error thrown either.
My angularJs code:

```
payment.factory("PaymentService", function ($http) {
return {
    getSearchresult: function ( callback) {
        return $http.get("/Payment/MigsPayment/InitiatePayment/").success(callback);
    }
  }
});
```

When I type in the browser:

http://localhost:52095/Payment/MigsPayment/InitiatePayment

the IntiatePayment view comes up. So what am I missing or making mistake?

Comment: what is your `callback` function doing? Does it actually accept the response data (not the response object) from the get request?

Comment: Hi justice O, yes it receives response, like

PaymentService.getSearchresult( function (response)
         {
           
         });
as you can see it does nothing with the response.

Comment: And if I dump the contents of respose, by JSON. stringify(response), I can see the entire content of strForm, and the contents of my MVC Razor view. so what should I do?

Comment: Set $scope.someVar to response.data (where response.data is html content)
Then in the view you can do <div ng-bind-html="someVar"></div>

If html contains angular js code that needs to be parsed, you would need to do $sce.trustAsHtml(contents) first.